# Can Velocity handle objects or just variables?

Tags: java, velocity

I am working with a velocity template right now and I'd like to know if I can pass in a Customer object or if I need to pass in the values independently?

For example, can I do `$customer.name`, `$customer.title`, etc. or do I need to keep doing `$name`, `$title`, etc? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can use the dot notation in velocity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Velocity user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#The_Mud_Store_Example), there is a section on methods where it shows the different ways to call methods on an object:

> **Methods**
>
> A method is defined in the Java code and is capable of doing
>   something useful, like running a calculation or arriving at a
>   decision. Methods are references that consist of a leading "$"
>   character followed a VTL Identifier, followed by a VTL Method Body. A
>   VTL Method Body consists of a VTL Identifier followed by an left
>   parenthesis character ("("), followed by an optional parameter list,
>   followed by right parenthesis character (")"). These are examples of
>   valid method references in the VTL:
>
> $customer.getAddress() $purchase.getTotal() $page.setTitle( "My Home
>   Page" ) $person.setAttributes( ["Strange", "Weird", "Excited"] )

and following that is a section on referencing object properties:

> **Property Lookup Rules**
>
> As was mentioned earlier, properties often
>   refer to methods of the parent object. Velocity is quite clever when
>   figuring out which method corresponds to a requested property. It
>   tries out different alternatives based on several established naming
>   conventions. The exact lookup sequence depends on whether or not the
>   property name starts with an upper-case letter. For lower-case names,
>   such as $customer.address, the sequence is
>
> ```
> getaddress()
> getAddress()
> get("address")
> isAddress()
> ```
>
> For upper-case property names like $customer.Address, it is slightly
>   different:
>
> ```
> getAddress()
> getaddress()
> get("Address")
> isAddress()
> ```

so yes, you can put objects in the Velocity context and refer to their fields.